# Mudar o API do projeto

Tags: android-studio

Estou com um aplicativo no android studio praticamente pronto, só que eu queria trocar de API 9 para o API 16 (Android 4.0).
Alguém pode explicar? Obrigada!

Comment: O API é usado, normalmente, em duas configurações do projeto: minSdkVersion e targetSdkVersion, que são API mínima e alvo, respectivamente. Qual delas você quer mudar? Publique o arquivo build.gradle(Module:app)  e/ou o manifesto pra poder te respoder
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu arquivo `build.gradle` dentro do módulo app (existem 2 mas só um tem essas linhas abaixo) você precisa mudar as linhas `minSdkVersion` de 9 pra 16, eu geralmente mantenho a `targetSdkVersion` pra mais alta, mas caso você queira mesmo apenas a 16, pode botar ali também.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yourapp.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(AppVersionCode)
    versionName AppVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Qualquer dúvida a mais só deixar um comentário mas é algo bem simples.

Se você falar ingles, esse [link](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.pkduaee9u) tem um artigo bem legal sobre isso

Comment: É só isso mesmo? Não tem outra coisa a ser feita?! Obrigada!!